# Help: Setting a Discrete Joint table.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

[image]

My first question is: If i did correctly the next table. For later calculate the asking probabilities.Thanks, again.

[image]

I follow the advise of kitman0804, and I worked in build the correct table, here I posted the table I build:

[image]

It is correct my answers for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't actually written down the table of $P_{XY}$. Write that down, and the rest of the questions are simply about looking in the appropriate rows/columns/diagonals of the table.

Comment: If the left side of your spreadsheet is supposed to represent the joint distribution, then it is not correct: remember that $X<Y$, and so there shouldn't be symmetry.  If the rows are $X$ and the columns are $Y$, then the top right half of your table should only contain zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Your first table is the probability mass function of first and second drawn number but not the probability mass table of $(X, Y)$ as @stochasticboy321 and @Nick Peterson said.

And I see that you are trying to find the marginal probability of $X$ and $Y$, but it may not help you to get the answers. Also, your table for $X$ and $P(X)$ is not correct neither ($\sum P(X) = 2.33 > 1$).

Actually, you can summarise the drawn numbers and values of $X$ and $Y$ by the following table:

```
| Drawn numbers | X |  Y | Probability  |
|---------------------------------------|
|  (1,2) (2,1)  | 1 |  2 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
|  (1,3) (3,1)  | 1 |  3 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
|  (1,4) (4,1)  | 1 |  4 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
|  (2,3) (3,2)  | 2 |  6 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
|  (2,4) (4,2)  | 2 |  8 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
|  (3,4) (4,3)  | 3 | 12 |  2/12 = 1/6  |
```

Then the probability mass function table of $p(x,y)$ can be made, which will help you solving the remaining questions.

Comment: I fixed my work, with your help. I hope is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Part (c) is asking for the p.m.f. of $Y|X=2$, i.e. the p.m.f. of $Y$ when $X=2$, so $p_{Y|X}(y|X=2)$ is not simply equal to $0.333$, it should be a function telling you the probability of $\{Y=y\}$, when it is known that $X=2$.

Comment: Also, some hints for part (d), if you want to show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, you need to prove $p_X(x)p_Y(y)=p(x,y)$ or $p_{Y|X}(y|X=x)=p_Y(y)$ or $p_{X|Y}(x|Y=y)=p_X(x)$, $\forall x ,y$, or give a counter example if you want to show that they are not independent.